# Unable to upgrade Expo CLI

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I have expo version 3.0.10 at the following location

```
$ expo --version
3.0.10

$ which expo
/usr/local/bin/expo
```

Now trying to upgrade expo cli

```
$ npm install -g expo-cli
...
[After some normal logs and optional dependency warnings]

+ expo-cli@3.11.7
added 96 packages from 42 contributors and updated 1 package in 88.788s
```

However, I still see the expo version as older version

```
$ expo --version
3.0.10
```

I have tried running with sudo as well with same result.
The node version on my machine v13.6.0, which gives a warning with npm but I don't think that is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several things I uninstalled node, npm, expo_cli and then reinstalled everything from scratch and now it works.